# How can I hide the container of a draggable but not the draggable itself?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am building a diagramming app. When a user clicks the panel he gets a pallet of shapes he can drag upon the canvas.
The app needs to be able to run on small devices such as tablets. So the pallet itself may take a lot of space or be on top of the drop location. So I want to hide the pallet (drag source) when te user starts dragging a shape from the pallet. In this way he can easily drop anywhere on the canvas.

How can I hide the pallet - without also hidding the draggable shape? 
I would also like to show the pallet again once the shape has been dropped so the user easily can choose another shape. I tried setting the css display property of the pallet, but that hides the dragged shape as well. I also tried to move the pallet to a z-index lower than the canvas, but that moves the shape as well to a z-index below the canvas.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution.
If I set css property "visibility" to "hidden" on the palette an force "visibility" to "visible" on the draggable, then it seems to work as desired.